# Use of articles in mathematical writing

Tags: articles, mathematics

I'm writing a section about some mathematical properties and have trouble with the use of articles (indefinite/definite/no).

I could come up with the following variants, but don't know which one is the correct one.
What I want to say is that if we pick any values for A and B, considering they are
integers, there will be items such as (A, B, 2), (A, B, 3), ..

Which article should come before item?

- For any A and any B, there will be an item (A, B, C) such that C > 1.
- For any A and any B, there will be item (A, B, C) such that C > 1.
- For any A and any B, there will be the item (A, B, C) such that C > 1.
- For any A and any B, there will be items (A, B, C) such that C > 1.
- For any A and any B, there will be items of the form (A, B, C) such that C > 1.

Comment: Is (A, B, C) functioning as a single item, such as a specific point in a 3-Dimensional plane? If so, use the first variation. If it is a group of three items, such as item A, item B, and item C, then use "For any A and any B, there will be items (A, B, C) such that C > 1."

Comment: What *exactly* do you wish to convey? Surely it makes a difference if there will *always* be exactly one, *sometimes* more than one, or *always* more than one item satisfying the condition. It's somewhat "domain-specific" whether **item (A, B, C)** validly identifies such an item, as opposed to calling it an **item of the form (A, B, C)**.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: ***None of the above***. Use mathematical language. *"For any integers A and B, there is an integer C>1 such that ..."*. And I don't know whether to complete this with *"an item of the form (A,B,C) exists"* or *"(A,B,C) is an item*" because I don't understand exactly what you want to say. Is the triple of integers an item, or are items something that is associated with a triple of integers?

Comment: @PeterShor - you should make that into an answer. These words have specific meanings in mathematics, which may or may not be related to the general usage. All of his examples make sense, but they have different meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct article to use is *"an"*. However, the fact that people don't actually understand what any of your sentences mean indicates that you are not being precise enough. Put the sentence in more mathematical language.

I think that what you mean is either:

> For any integers *A* and *B*, there is an integer *C* > 1 such that an item of the form (*A,B,C*) exists,

or

> For any integers *A* and *B*, there is an integer *C* > 1 such that (*A,B,C*) is an item.

Which of these you should use depends on the exact definition of an *item*, which we cannot deduce from your question.

Comment: Thanks, I asked another question which I believe is a more accurate version of this one: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208902/the-use-of-article-when-an-element-is-defined-before